Remove margins from aa image used as a background in pyqt5
I am tryiyng to remove an image's margins (or padding?) used as background image in mi app. I use a QLabel to place the image as the centralWidget of my mainwindow, but then when a initialize the app it looks like this:
![enter image description here][1]
the code is simple:
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import qtstylish
import os
import sys

basedir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        bg_image = QtGui.QIcon(basedir + "/resources/fondoHome/light_bg.png").pixmap(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self)
        label.setPixmap(bg_image)

        btn = QtWidgets.QAction(parent=self, icon=QtGui.QIcon(basedir + "/resources/light/iconosSVGAzules/new_client.svg"))

        toolbar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(parent=self)
        toolbar.setMovable(False)
        toolbar.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(32, 32))
        self.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.LeftToolBarArea, toolbar)
        toolbar.addAction(btn)
        
        self.setStyleSheet(qtstylish.light())
        self.setCentralWidget(label)
        self.resize(1920, 1080)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()


Calling setScaledContents() on a child label not managed by a layout is useless. From your code it's unclear how the central widget is set (a Designer UI file? pyuic generated code? manually handled?), so it's impossible to provide an appropriate answer right now unless you provide a valid [mre]. In any case, there are two possible solutions, but none of them can rely on QLabel, as it doesn't provide fixed aspect ratio: either subclass the QWidget used as central widget, and manually draw the background in paintEvent(), or do that in QMainWindow based on the central widget geometry.

@musicamante ok, I am going to modify the post to insert a mre

@musicamante done it! I want to point out that I tried not to use self.setStyleSheet(qtstylish.light()) in the code and the margins problem disappeared, so maybe is a configuration in the package that is causing the problem. Anyway, I am going to apply your suggested solutions and give you a feedback

The problem with using such external modules that alter the overall styling is that you can never be sure about what actually happens "under the hood". Qt Style Sheets are quite powerful, but they are also extremely delicate and, therefore, weak. 1. they completely depend on the underlying style (that of the QApplication or the specific style set on a widget); 2. that style may not provide complete support for QSS, which results in awkward results depending on the OS and user configuration; 3. they are not cumulative, meaning that there's no absolute way to "apply" rules on a provided QSS »

» or the other way around: QSS are computed internally, and there is no direct way to know what rule is being applied at a given moment, since QSS can be inherited and the parser has no public API. An "overall" QSS based solution is most surely based on lots of exceptions and prone to issues, especially considering that even the standard QStyles ('fusion' and 'windows') are sometimes unreliable under certain circumstances. I don't know about qtstylish, but I know for a fact that almost any attempt in providing a "module" that just uses QSS for styling fails at a certain point, and the few »

» that don't actually work because they switched to the pure QStyle implementation. In any case, advanced use of QSS requires knowing a lot about what QStyle does and how it works. Unless you know for sure that the QSS based module you're using is fully aware about these aspects (and there's no way to know about that), you have to be prepared to the fact that whenever you want to override their behavior you'll almost certainly face an inconsistent or unexpected behavior at some point, possibly caused by other users having different configurations.

@musicamante so you recommend me to built my own QStyleSheet?

No. I recommend to learn more about how Qt Style work. QSS are powerful as they are complex to deal with and, to some extent, unreliable. They are fine for simple/enclosed (and aware) cases, but, for complex applications (custom widgets, extended widget structures) they may also become a huge limitation. Creating your own QSS isn't impossible, but, as stated above, you may reach a point where you get its limits. Remember that appearance and design must be functional, and what you see on your computer is almost never what everybody else will.

As @deviep11 suggested the solution was to add a new style to qtstylish. The final and working code is:
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
import qtstylish
import os
import sys

basedir = os.path.dirname(__file__)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        bg_image = QtGui.QIcon(basedir + "/resources/fondoHome/dark_bg.png").pixmap(QtCore.QSize(1920, 1080))
        label = QtWidgets.QLabel(parent=self)
        label.setPixmap(bg_image)

        btn = QtWidgets.QAction(parent=self, icon=QtGui.QIcon(basedir + "/resources/light/iconosSVGAzules/new_client.svg"))

        toolbar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(parent=self)
        toolbar.setMovable(False)
        toolbar.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(32, 32))
        self.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.LeftToolBarArea, toolbar)
        toolbar.addAction(btn)

        additional_style = "QLabel { border: none; padding: 0px; }"  ## <-- insert this line

        self.setStyleSheet(qtstylish.light() + additional_style)  ## <-- add the new style to qtstylish
        self.setCentralWidget(label)
        self.resize(1920, 1080)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle("Fusion")
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()

